# Foreign key allow null SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, null, foreign-keys

please check it this two tables.

```
create table Panda (id int identity, koalaId null) 
create table Koala (id int identity)
```

I need that `koalaId` was foreign key to table Koala -> identity, but also I need that `koalaId` can be a `NULL`.

After this will be resolved, I need get data from Panda, but I get only a error:

> Property koalaId for Panda not be set to null. This property must be set to a value that is not null and is of type Int32.

And I want for `koalaId` set to `null`.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Remove Foreign key. **EDIT** Or check this out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/325c11b9-e5c4-4db7-94e6-f82b44412b9b/is-it-possible-to-allow-null-values-in-foreign-key?forum=transactsql

Comment: That message is not an SQL one - there's no inherent limitation in SQL Server's foreign keys that prevent nulls. So whatever limitation you're facing, it's in `<X>` where `<X>` is whatever tool, library or framework you're using to interface with the database. Which you've given us no information about.

Comment: There must be something else, since fields with FKs in SQL Server can be nullable.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Your error message looks similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502872/efcode-first-property-null-problem

Comment: Yes, I am susing Enity Framewrok, and my problem is solved.
Thank you everybody for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a foreign key column will allow null value. you don't want to mention it explicitly.

```
**for example:**
             Create table Kola(Id numeric identity(1,1) primary key)
             Create table Panda(Id numeric identity(1,1),
                                KolaId numeric references Kola(Id))
```

**Note:**But make sure column 'id' in table 'kola' should be a primary key before it get referenced
by another table.

Answer (score 0):

here is Panda and Cola creation codes:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kola](
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [kolaName] [nchar](10) NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Kola] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,                           ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

---

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Panda](
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [KolaId] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Panda] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Panda]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Panda_Kola] FOREIGN         KEY([KolaId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Kola] ([id])
    GO

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Panda] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Panda_Kola]
    GO
```