# Trying to set a non-null string to type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Entity Framework is throwing this exception:

> The 'PasswordIterations' property on 'BranchIdentity' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'.

It's throwing on this line:

```
// Validate uniqueness or email and username
var user = sqlStorage.BranchIdentities.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Username.ToLower() == viewModel.Username.ToLower());
```

The exception only throws when there is an entity that matches the query. If there are no matches, the exception isn't thrown.

My BranchIdentity model:

```
namespace Branch.Models.Sql
{
    public class BranchIdentity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PasswordIterations { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BranchIdentitySession> BranchIdentitySessions { get; set; } 

        public virtual BranchRole BranchRole { get; set; }

        public virtual GamerIdentity GamerIdentity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my schema (taken from the sql database) - auto-generated using code-first migrations:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BranchIdentities] (
    [Id]                 INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Username]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordSalt]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [PasswordIterations] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Email]              NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [BranchRole_Id]      INT            NULL,
    [GamerIdentity_Id]   INT            NULL,
    [FullName]           NVARCHAR (MAX) DEFAULT ('') NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.BranchIdentities] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BranchIdentities_dbo.BranchRoles_BranchRole_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([BranchRole_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[BranchRoles] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.BranchIdentities_dbo.GamerIdentities_GamerIdentity_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([GamerIdentity_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[GamerIdentities] ([Id])
);
```

I have tried making `PasswordIterations` nullable, but to no avail.

Comment: Your `PasswordIterations` is defined as `Nullable<int>`. So obviously you can't use string.

Comment: The thing is, i'm not using a string anywhere at all. It's always an int.

Comment: I doubt it's that line which throwing the exception. Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, http://i.imgur.com/jMMA706.png

Comment: What code tried to insert the data, not to read it?

Comment: Why is PasswordIterations Nullable if it's [Required]? Perhaps this is confusing EF?

Comment: What happens when you change Nullable<int> to int?

Comment: @abatishchev: i'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: @MikeG and co, It was originally int, but I changed it to Nullable<int> just to see if that would fix it. To no avail.

Comment: But what about "int?" ?

Comment: int? is exactly the same as Nullable<int> - I just prefer the syntax

Comment: I am guessing your EDMX is corrupt. Try rebuilding it. Follow [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13422199/3437575

Comment: @asb I'm using CodeFirst Migrations, I don't have an EDMX.

Comment: If you know that your Int32 PasswordIterations will never be null then you should not mark it as nullable. That is what is confusing EF, you've added a Required attribute, but marked the property as nullable. This you cannot do.

Comment: Remove `[Required]` from `PasswordIterations` or change it to `public int PasswordIterations { get; set;}`

Comment: I set it to nullable to try and fix the issue. Originally it wasn't nullable - I've updated my example to show this.

Comment: Does this error throw when there actually is a matching record in your database?  I feel like Entity Framework is getting confused when trying to construct your default object.

Comment: It actually only throws when there is an entry in the database that matches

Comment: "It actually only throws when there is an entry in the database that matches"
This is because EF will only try to create an instance of BranchIdentities once your query returns. The call to FirstOrDefault is actually converted to SQL and executed server side. The first thing to do is to figure out where does that string comes from. Try to run the query with the SQL Server Profiler running. This will let you see the actual SQL query the server processes and the data it returns. Maybe the data doesn't quite look like what you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for anyone else having issues with this. Set a breakpoint in `DatabaseContext` and make sure it's connecting to the correct database. Mine was being overwritten from a web.config file I forgot about.

Comment: Thanks.  I had public int foo instead of public string foo.  geez.

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like your schema and the Entity don't match up, You posted your Code first generated code but that might have changed since the table was created. take a look at the table in SQL Server Manager and double check the data type for that column.

Comment: The schema I posted was from the database, rather the CodeFirst migration. I'll update my question to clarify.

Comment: I put your posted schema and EF model into my solution and it worked great.  Then I changed the database type of PasswordIterations to a varchar and got the precise exception you show above.  This answer is almost certainly the right answer, so I would double and triple check your connection strings.  Also, running SQL Server Profiler would be a great step.  If it shows no activity, then your project isn't connecting to the db you think it is.

Comment: You were right. It was connecting to some random database.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this SO post on the way to solving a similar problem.

I found that my stored procedure had conditional logic that could return either a string or an int for the first column in the result set.

EF seemed to pick up the first bit of result set code it found, which returned a string.

I fixed this by having the sproc return a string either way.

Answer (score 2):

If it's nullable why do you have it marked as required? Remove the required flag and it should behave as expected.

Comment: I set it to nullable to try and fix the issue. Originally it wasn't nullable - I've updated my example to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a proc import into the EF model and it turned out that the select statement had changed.EF was seeing the result field as a string rather than the int which was defined in the original generated model.  We had to explicitly cast the field in the proc to an int and all was happy again.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility of such error, I had seen after changing data type from `string` to `int`.

Before change

```
public string foo { get; set; }
```

After change

```
public int foo { get; set; }
```

Before this change, `string` will allow inserting `null` values into the table. After change, those old **nulls can become reason of throwing such errors.**

## Replace null values in table with number (eg: 0)

Answer (score 1):

in my real database my field was null able int but in my Model in code my field was simple int. I changed it to int? (nullable int) and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with View. With an explicit cast to nvarchar of the problematic column in the view script and an update of the model it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

The Question is resolved but it may be useful for someone else:

make sure you write the correct connection to the database and you can make the c# generate the connection string for you by:
add a new item --> Data -->ADO.Net entity datamodel -->code first from database --->New Connection ---> and specify your parameters and test connection -->ok -->ok -->till finish

open web.config and you will find your connection string

---

also check if there is a nullable column in the database implement it in your class as follows :
for ex: public int? WorkedYears { get; set; }
ref:[EFCode First Property Null problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502872/efcode-first-property-null-problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too . for example  if you use int16 or short in your model you should set your column in table to smallint and if you set by int certainly it wont work fine. this issue is related to yours.
hope this help.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help someone, the error i saw was:

> The 'Taller' property on 'ApplicationUser' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'.

In my case, i changed the type of Taller column in my database User Table, i also changed this in my EF model. But if you are using identity, you should check also you usermanager (IdentityModels), overthere you define the custom columns for your user table.