# 'The 'Id' property on 'IdentityUser`4' could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value

Tags: c#, .net

I get this error when trying to log in providing an email which is in my sql database.

> 'The 'Id' property on 'IdentityUser`4' could not be set to a
> 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
> of type 'System.String'. '

As I see in the error, there is an unusual apostrophe in the word Identityuser and i dont know where this number 4 came from. It is same for every testcase. Im using Identity sample library for account controller. Using .net4.5 framework.

This is my Account Controler method. I have mentioned where i get the error

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards lockout only two factor authentication
        // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        
        var user = SignInManager.UserManager.Users.Where(u => u.Email == model.Email).FirstOrDefault();
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); //getting error here

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

This is my identityModels

```
using GiftSmart.DataModel;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace IdentitySample.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("GiftSmartContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        static ApplicationDbContext()
        {
            // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
            // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
            //Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
            //Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>());
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<GiftSmartContext>());
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {

            return "Data Source=CL-KASUNP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=giftsmart_live;Integrated Security=True;";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434112/trying-to-set-a-non-null-string-to-type-system-int32

Comment: @johhan85 As in this question there is a branchIdentity class defined by developer. but in my case, there isnt identity user class. Its a bulit in class from identitySample library